# Show $S_N = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \text{sign}(Y-X_n)$ is Markov, $(X_n),Y $ iid Uniform(0,1)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $(X_n)$ and Y be i.i.d. Uniform$(0,1)$ random variables and let 
$$S_N = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \text{sign}(Y-X_n)$$

Show that $S_n$ is a Markov Chain and find its transition probabilities.

Any help with this one?

Its clear that $\mathbb{P}(S_N = x\,\,\vert\,\, S_{n-1},...S_0) = \mathbb{P}([(S_N = x)\cap S_{N-1} = x-1]\cup[(S_N = x)\cap S_{N-1} = x+1]\,\,\vert\,\, S_{n-1},...S_0) = \mathbb{P}([(S_N = x)\cap S_{N-1} = x-1]\cup[(S_N = x)\cap S_{N-1} = x+1]\,\,\vert\,\, S_{N-1})$

How would you find the transitional probabilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $u=(S_n+n)/2$ is [$Beta-Binomial(n,1,1)=U[0,n]$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution). Hence $$Y|S_n\sim Beta(1+\frac{n+S_n}2,1+\frac{n-S_n}2)=Beta(1+u,1+d)$$ with average $\hat y_n=\frac {1+u}{2+u+d}=\frac{1+u}{n+2}$ and hence $$S_{n+1}-S_n|S_n\sim B(P((Y|S_n)>X_{n+1}))= B(\hat y_n)$$
where $B(p)$ is Bernoulli on $\{-1,1\}$ with $P(B(p)=1)=p$.

Comment: Nice answer. Please modify the incorrect $P((Y|S_n)>X_{n+1})$.

Comment: @Did Are you protesting using the same notation for both a conditional distribution and a random variable with that distribution?

Comment: @Did, how would you write the expression?

Comment: Answer: Conditionally on $S_n$, $S_{n+1}-S_n\sim B(p(S_n))$ with $$p(S_n)=P(Y>X_{n+1}\mid S_n).$$

Comment: @Did How is $P(Y>X_{n+1}|S_n)$ not equal to $P((Y|S_n)>X_{n+1})$ given that $X_{n+1}$ is independent of $Y$ and $S_n$?

Comment: Independence is not involved. Rather the trouble is that the object $(U\mid V)$ for some random variables $U$ and $V$ is not even defined hence, unfortunately, $P((U\mid V)>W)$ does not exist. If one means instead $P(U>W\mid V)$ (a perfectly well defined random variable), one can simply write this.

Comment: $U|V$ is well-defined as a collection of distributions indexed by range of $V$ which can also be viewed as a collection of random variables with those distribution. As a result, $P((U|V)>W)$ is well-defined as a function of $V$..

Comment: No. If $(U\mid V)$ is a "collection of distributions", what could $P((U\mid V)>W)$ even *mean*? We know what is $P(Z>W)$ if $Z$ is a random variable, not if $Z$ is a distribution. (Unrelated: Please use @ if you want your comment to be notified.)

Comment: @Did   $U|V$ "can be viewed as a collection of random variables with those distributions". That is you can view $P(D_1>D_2)$ as $P(X_1>X_2)$ where $X_i\sim D_i$ are independent.

Comment: So now $U\mid V$ is supposed to denote a collection of random variables, not of distributions? Anyway, your last suggestion (which seems to have been concocted on the spot) does not work either. My suggestion: stick to the canon, and use the well defined setting I underlined in my comments (or provide a plausible full alternative setting...).

Comment: You asked me what it could mean. I gave you an answer. The OP understood my notation exactly as intended while you still haven't shown exactly how the above definition "doesn't work". My suggestion: look beyond the canon, use your imagination and realize that there are other modes of thinking. Strict adherence to the gospel gives you a sizable blind spot.

Comment: "I gave you an answer." No. Or rather: which one? The "collection of distributions" one or the "collection of random variables" one? That you are unable to even *define* the notions you use here is only logical since *this is not how conditional distributions are defined or used, nowhere, never*. Now, since the rest of your last comment is poetry in the bad sense of the term and since, from the start, I indicated the way to repair your post, way which is here for everybody to read, I think I will consider my task is done...

Comment: @Did $U|V$ is *both* a collection of distributions and a collection of (independent) random variables with those distributions. The two notions are equivalent and are used as such *everywhere* - outside of your gospel that is. The second identification leads to $P(Y>X_{n+1}|S_n)=P((Y|S_n)>X_{n+1})$ since $X_{n+1}$ is independent of $Y$ and $S_n$. What is unclear?

Comment: No, $U\mid V$ is not a collection of random variables, never, nowhere. That is, to those who play the game you call "gospel" and that everybody else call "mathematics". (The (timid but repeated) addition of the (irrelevant) mention "independent" in your comment is funny and signals a point where the half baked (and rather vague) construction you have in mind (which, rather strangely if one considers its daring originality, you still did not explain) utterly fails.)

Comment: @Did 1. $U|V$ is a collection of distributions. 2.$P(D_1>D_2):=P(X_1>X_2)$ for $X_i\sim D_i$ independent. What are your objections?

Comment: That your 1. does not apply to your 2. since $D_1$ in your 2. is a random variable while your 1. deals with distributions. *Capisce*? (You know, instead of reinventing (wrongly) the wheel, contradicting yourself from comment to comment, and throwing around ridiculous considerations of "gospel", "imagination", "modes of thinking" and whatnot, an alternative would be *to grab a textbook on the subject and to read it*. Or, maybe you are simply playing the troll and I fell in the trap, beautifully...)

Comment: Are you deliberately misreading notation? $D_i$ in 2. stands for *D*istribution and $X_i$ stands for random variable distributed according to $D_i$. In the notation of your first comment, $p(s_n)=P((Y|S_n)(s_n)>(X_{n+1}|S_n)(s_n))=P(D_1>D_2)=P(X_1>X_2)$. What's unclear?

Comment: **Nobody** uses the notation $P(\alpha>\beta)$ for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ some distributions, **ever**. What does "$\alpha>\beta$" for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ some distributions, **even mean** (if one is not alluding to stochastic ordering, offtopic in the present context)? OK: the "troll hypothesis" is confirmed.

Comment: @Did I defined $P(\alpha>\beta)$, not $\alpha>\beta$. What does $X|\mathcal F$ even mean - without the expectation?

Comment: Is this some kind of damage control?

Comment: @Did No, it's a demonstration that $\alpha>\beta$ doesn't have to have meaning on its own. Returning to my very first response to you, it's extremely unambiguous what $(Y|S_n)$ in $P((Y|S_n)>X_{n+1})$ stands for - a random variable distributed as $(Y|S_n)(S_n)$ independent of $X_{n+1}$. Is this abuse of notation? Somewhat. But when random variables are independent (as in this case), you can safely identify them with their distributions without losing any information. There is a reason why most r.v. are not explicitly constructed but are simply described by their (joint) distributions.

Comment: Blablabla. Once again (and for the last time): 1. Nobody uses the notation $P((U\mid V)>W)$, never, and you know it. 2. This notational "invention" of yours brings nothing, and you know it. 3. There is a perfecly rigorous way to denote what you seem to have in mind, and you know it. // Additionally, I have rarely seen anyone react with such negativity to (rather basic) remarks about their answers (yes, even on this site). Frankly this is baffling (and be aware that next time I will be less patient to explain things).

Comment: @Did *I* use this notation - it reflects how I think and makes relevant info visible (I could write $P(N(0,1)>N(1,1))$ instead of $P(X_1>X_2)$). How would *you* compute $p(S_n)=P(Y>X_{n+1}|S_n)$? // Reread my comments ITT. You seem to consider me pointing out that your (repeated) rigid adherence to a single canon limits your scope to be "such negativity". I don't. Did I hit a nerve? I'm reacting to your pedantry, not your canon. // Example of your limited scope ITT: you first baselessly claim that $U|V$ is not defined and then baselessly claim that $P(D_1>D_2)$ *can't* be a rigorous shorthand.

Comment: "Baselessly", as in, "following universal usage"? Enough.

Comment: @Did $\ U|V$ is *universally* used (outside of your canon that is). $P(D_1>D_2)$ is my own shorthand for which I provided "full alternative setting" per your request.

Comment: It is becoming flagrant that you are engaged in a kind of damage control operation, which, unfortunately, is not very convincing: yes, the notation $U\mid V$ is somewhat relaxed but acceptable, no, the notation $P((U\mid V)>W)$ is neither acceptable nor used. Oops, did I already mention quite clearly the fact several times? Bonus remark: if $(U\mid V)$ is a random variable, as you insist on, what could be $(U\mid V)(v)$ (your invention, again) for $v$ in the target set of $V$? Answer: [A chimera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chimera_(mythology)).

Comment: @Did Reread my 3rd comment. I stated that $U|V$ stands for a collection of *distributions* (there is nothing relaxed about it) and $(U|V)(v)$ is one member of this collection. I view random variables/their distributions as extremely closely related concepts and as such $(U|V)(v)$ is also a shorthand for a random variable with distribution $(U|V)(v)$ (when there is no ambiguity involved). Such usage in my answer caused no ambiguity as evidenced by OP's acceptance/bounty.

Comment: And yet another gem (when one *invents* notations outside of the *canon*, such inconsistencies are to be expected): if $(U\mid V)$ and $W$ are random variables, then $P((U\mid V)>W)$ is a *number*, right? Say, $P((U\mid V)>W)=p$, then your result is that $S_{n+1}-S_n$ conditionally on $S_n$ is binomial with parameter $p$? This is false.

Comment: @Did No. $P((U|V)>W)$ is not a number but a function of $V$ because $W$ is not a single $W$ but a collection of $W$ indexed by $V$. I assume you've never seen vectorized code (e.g. MATLAB)?

Comment: Digging deeper and deeper. Good luck...

Comment: @Did Allow me to quote you: "the object $(U∣V)$ for some random variables $U$ and $V$ is not even defined" - did you mis-type suddenly? As for your second point, the purpose of notation is to communicate the content. The content behind my atypical notation was understood by at least 2 people (including you) and I'm content with that. My choice of notation reflects how I think and compute. How would *you* compute $p(S_n)=P(Y>X_{n+1}|S_n)$?

Comment: @Did I will assume that you mistyped in your first comment and indeed recognize that $U|V$ can stand for a collection of distributions. On the other hand, one often sees $U|V\sim D(V)$. Is it not natural to interpret $U|V$ in this expression as a collection of random variables s.t. $(U|V)(v)=(U|V=v)\sim D(v)$? What do you say?

Comment: That you are not reading what others explain to you and that your attitude makes that I do not feel any obligation to correct your misconceptions anymore.

Comment: @Did All you (and this is the second time you equated yourself with multiple "others") are saying is that "$P((U|V)>W)$ is neither acceptable nor used". I agree with you on the latter but disagree on the former since a) it was understood by others b) it is intuitive (to me), can be rigorously defined and choice of notation is a matter of personal taste. Aside from that, I'm *genuinely* curious as to how you would compute $p(S_n)=P(Y>X_{n+1}|S_n)$ in a way different from the one I wrote (which, in my notation, is $=P((Y|S_n)>(X_{n+1}|S_n))$).

Comment: Ahhh... Finally you got the notion that the correct notation for the quantity of interest is $P(U>V\mid W)$. **Congratulations!**

Comment: @Did Did I ever deny that? I simply skipped that step in my calculations: $P(U>V|W)=P((U|W)>V)$ for $V$ independent of $W$ and $U$. So how do *you* compute $P(Y>X_{n+1}|S_n)$ in this scenario?

Comment: Yes you did, absurdly, exhaustingly. (Next time, please spare us the stupid thread of comments and correct right away your answer, right?)

Comment: @Did can you quote me doing that? My second reply to you ITT is "How is $P(Y>X_{n+1}|S_n)$ not equal to $P((Y|S_n)>X_{n+1})$ given that $X_{n+1}$ is independent of $Y$ and $S_n$?" You seem to want to score so much that you are constantly moving the goal posts - and still missing.

Comment: Answer not corrected yet.

Comment: @Did or A.S.   Could you please provide some more explanation of how do we take each of the above assertions? Thank you in advance

Comment: @perlman If I may venture a suggestion... This page is an example of MSE turning bad: an incorrect answer, never corrected, accepted by an OP who probably does not quite understand it, nothing worthy of your study 1.5 years later. If you are interested in old stuff, try to rather study **good** old answers.

Comment: @Did Thanks for your response. I want to see a solution to this exercise, that's why I asked for some clarification since I cannot see how we take each step. Also, is this in general incorrect or just at the point you were discussing in the above comments?

Comment: @perlman In such cases, it is recommended that you ask your own question, possibly linking it to this page, explaining precisely what it is you are not figuring out in the solution.

Comment: @Did Ok, I didn't know that, thanks for mentioning it. The truth is that I can't follow almost any step, so since I didn't have a specific question I asked generally for some details to be added in the proof. Thanks again for your responses

Comment: @perlman I am not surprised that the answer does not satisfy an honest reader. At the time, I did what I could to bring the OP to correct their... well, imprecisions, shall we say? With no success at all, as you can read in the comments thread above. And the behavior of the author of the question, offering a bounty and accepting a post they probably did not even understand, did not help. Better to move on...